# Как получить значения поля id и байта don't fragment при получении пакета из обычного tcp сокета на linux?

Tags: android, c++, linux, http, tcp

Хочу добавить в свою программу, которая обходит DPI, возможность блокировки пассивного DPI.
Имеется tcp сокет, с помощью которого осуществляется общение с заблокированным сервером. Для удачного обмана пассивного DPI необходимо не обращать внимание на пакеты, у которых поля id и don't fragment равны 1. Вопрос: как мне узнать значение полей из заголовка IP принятого мной пакета? Root использовать нельзя.

Comment: Для raw socket нужен рут, а у меня приложение для android, которое должно работать без рут.